# How to add numbers entered by user in Javascript

Tags: javascript

The following is the JavaScript I did in order to try to add two numbers entered by the user but the result I'm getting is "NaN":

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>JavaScript-Functions</TITLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY>

<H1>JavaScript-Functions</H1>

<P>This function will add two numbers.</P>

<script type="text/JavaScript">

<!-- This is a math function -->

var x = prompt("Please enter the first number: ");
var y = prompt("Please enter the second number: ");

function addTwo(x, y)
{
 var xNum;
 xNum = parseInt(x);
 var yNum;
 yNum = parseInt(y);     
 return xNum + yNum;
}

document.write(addTwo(x, y));

</script>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Works fine for me [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5WS57/), you get `NaN` if input is not number

Comment: yup works fine for me too in Chrome browser. Which browser you are using? Also make sure javascript is enabled on the browser.

Comment: Unclear why people are downvoting this question...I just confirmed it does work in Firefox on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Everything looks good here, except the html comment

```
<!-- This is a math function -->
```

in script tag.

Comment: Thank you "SPS" your answer solved my problem. I deleted the comment that was misplaced and the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

If you give numbers as a input means it'll surely work otherwise it throws error "NaN".

Answer (score 0):

try to use callback. This is due to the asynchronous evented I/O model of javascript.

```
var x = prompt("Please enter the first number: ");
var y = prompt("Please enter the second number: "); 

function addTwo(x, y, callback){
 var xNum;
 xNum = parseInt(x);
 var yNum;
 yNum = parseInt(y);  
 var result = xNum + yNum;
 callback(result);
}

addTwo(x, y, function(result){
  document.write(result);
});
```

[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/raunay/pen/GowbH) EDITED:link

Answer (score 0):

You could get rid of the `parseInt()`s and put a `+` in front of the prompt. That will parse the prompt response and change it from a string to an integer.

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">

<!-- This is a math function -->

var x = +prompt("Please enter the first number: ");
var y = +prompt("Please enter the second number: ");


document.write(x, y);

</script>
```

Just like that. So iv'e counted three things the `+` sign can do:
1. Concatenate strings and variables
2. It's like a `parseInt()` when placed in front of a window object
3. and its usual function, to add integers.